# Taxonomy Has Terms bug?

Tags: orchardcms

I use Orchard 1.10.1. I created a Content-Type called product（include 2 taxonomy).

The taxonomy are Category(book,toy,clothing) and color(red,blue,black).

When Filters taxonomy term in the dashboard,
I choose Has Terms and Category with is one of（filters Category,not color）.
but, The filters display all(Category,color) Content Items.

why! please help,Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz7f3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhu5Y.png)

Comment: Can you include some screenshots of your filter configuration for clarification?

Comment: In your second screenshot I can see that you selected both 'Category' **AND** 'color'

Comment: when created  term .I only  selected  'Category" ,then,I  opened  Filtes again.looked  like   selected both 'Category' AND 'color'

Comment: I have a ContentType( product) that have 2 taxonomy (book,toy,clothing)  and color(red,blue,black).  Now,I want to display statistics . Example,(book:30pages toy:20pages clothing:50pages).